# Calculate number of list items for each list separate and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I'm trying something simple(?), to calculate the number of list items and append it to the list in the parent div. The problem is it is always taking the value of the last, as you can see the first list has 4 items and says 4/2 where this should be 4/4.. How to solve this?

Thanks

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tZLG9/

Code:

```
$(".list_slides_pagination li a").each(function() {
    list_slides_count = $(".list_slides").find(".list_slides_pagination").length;
    $(this).append("/" + list_slides_count);
    console.log(list_slides_count)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always referring to the same list... You should use this :

```
$(this).closest(".list_slides_pagination").find("li").length;
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/tZLG9/3/

Comment: Of all the answers given, on average, this is the slowest across all browsers. Just for interest sake.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$(".list_slides").each(function () {
  var list_slides = $(this).find(".list_slides_pagination li a");
  list_slides.each(function () {
    $(this).append("/" + list_slides.length);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **[something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/tZLG9/1/)**. if Yes then use the following approach

```
$(".list_slides_pagination").each(function () {
    var num_li = $('li', $(this)).length
    $('li a', $(this)).each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html() + '/' + num_li);
    })
});
```

1. for each `<ul>`
2. count number of `<li>` it
3. traverse each `<a>` inside the `<ul>` and append that count to it

Comment: Just so you know, as of jQuery 1.4 the [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml) can be re-written like this: `$(this).html(function(i,html){ return html + '/' + num_li; });`

Comment: @Mottie thanks for adding useful information to the page (y)!

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
$(".list_slides_pagination li").each(function() {
            list_slides_count =     $(this).parent().find("li").length;
            $(this).append("/" + list_slides_count);

            console.log(list_slides_count)
 });
```

[Working JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZLG9/6/)

Answer (score 1):

use that code :

```
$(".list_slides_pagination").each(function() {
    list_slides_count = $(this).find("li").length;
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){          
        $(this).append("/" + list_slides_count);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you in jquery (it may not be the most concise jquery syntax though)

```
$(".list_slides_pagination").each(function (index1, element) {
    var items = $("li a", element),
        count = items.length;

    items.each(function (index2, item) {
        item.textContent = item.textContent + "/" + count;
    });
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/zW7rA/)

And here was my original javascript thought, which I translated to above. For demonstration to @roasted

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".list_slides_pagination"), function (element) {
    var items = element.querySelectorAll("li a"),
        count = items.length;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, function (item) {
        item.textContent = item.textContent + "/" + count;
    });
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Yr3vx/)

And here we have a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/calculate-number-of-list-items) of all the solutions given, not just mine, so that we have a performance guide.

Comment: Well, that would be because I wouldn't use jquery for this but vanilla javascript (thinking forEach) and so I translated it direct. But you could expand on why a loop in a loop is a bad idea.